# How to update link caption in navigation field dynamically during runtime in Sitecore SXA 9.3

Tags: sxa

I am trying to update 'link caption in navigation' field from Query String in breadcrumb component.

Here is out of the box breadcrumb code:

```
@Html.RenderingVariants().RenderVariant(variantField, item.Item, Model.IsControlEditable, Model);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you would like to change the text displayed in the breadcrumbs based on information from the querystring.

The breadcrumb component uses variants, so you can use variants to display what you want. In your case you might want to create a new one (or update the default breadcrumb variant). As you will see in the default variant, SXA uses fallbacks here to check values in fields - if the navigation title is empty it checks the title and then the display name. You can use the same mechanism and put the querystring data on top.

Reading data from the querystring however is not standard available as option in a variant. As you are using v9.3 though, you can use Scriban. Even there, the querystring is not ootb but you could extend with your logic to get what you need. At https://ggullentops.blogspot.com/2019/11/custom-sxa-scriban-extensions.html you can see how to write your own context function where you can return querystring data (or empty). Would be something like:

```
using Scriban.Runtime;
using Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Abstractions;
using Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Scriban.Pipelines.GenerateScribanContext;

public class ScribanQuerystring : IGenerateScribanContextProcessor
{
    public void Process(GenerateScribanContextPipelineArgs args)
    {
        var query = new GetQuerystring(Querystring);
        args.GlobalScriptObject.Import("sc_querystring", (Delegate)query);
    }

    public string Querystring(string key)
    {
        // get querystring value for "key" (and optionally other logic)
    }

    private delegate string GetQuerystring(string key);
}
```

Register your function in the `generateScribanContext` pipeline.

Comment: Thank you, I created my own view code to do it